# Customize radio button in HTML and remove checkable circle

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a question,
is there any way to customize radio button and use checkable Card instead of that checkable circles?

I'm working on multiple choice questions and need it for making question view more attractive. Here is the basic radiogroup.
I want is to select just a card not the the default check button.

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems a bit vague and might be answerable if you add some more details and examples of what you've already tried. See [guidelines for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're not sure how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    
}

.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}


.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

.container .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
 left: 9px;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is resource that I used a while back that helped me build custom radio buttons for a project: [Code Pen Example of Custom Radio Buttons](https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/raQmpL)

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #F87DA9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">Apple</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">Peach</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test3">Orange</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still it has the circle . I want to be a group of cards behave like radio button

Comment: in your css add `input{visibility: invisible;}`